# FFProbe not sending custom Headers

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to use FFprobe with a custom header that enables me to access the multimedia information such as frame-rate, bit-rates and etc of an URL. Custom Headers (-headers) were set based on the ffmpeg documentation and tutorials examples.

Command snippet:

`ffprobe -headers $'X-CloudFront-Secret: A-VALID-TOKEN' -v error -show_format -show_streams -print_format json -i "URL"`

It returns a 403 Forbidden message.

cURL-ing the URL with the custom header yields a 200 Response.

Am I setting the ffprobe custom header right?

Thank you!